# Specifying a multi-state model with unobservable terminal state

Tags: references, survival, transition-matrix, recurrent-events

Suppose there is a multi-state process with three states, listed below and labelled as terminal/non-terminal and observable/unobservable:

1. **Initializing**: non-terminal observable
2. **Active**: non-terminal observable
3. **Inactive**: non-terminal observable
4. **Inactive Forever**: terminal unobservable
5. **Terminated**: terminal observable

The following transitions can occur:

1. Initializing $\rightarrow$ Active (observable)
2. Initializing $\rightarrow$ Inactive (observable)
3. Active $\rightarrow$ Inactive (observable)
4. Inactive $\rightarrow$ Active (observable)
5. Inactive $\rightarrow$ Initalizing (observable)
6. Inactive $\rightarrow$ Inactive Forever (unobservable)
7. Active $\rightarrow$ Terminated (observable)
8. Inactive $\rightarrow$ Terminated (observable)
9. Initializing $\rightarrow$ Terminated (observable)

In this study, the transition trajectory from Inactive $\rightarrow$ Active $\rightarrow$ Inactive forever is of particular interest. We are not interested in specifying an arbitrary temporal cutoff to define the Inactive Forever state.

Any insights or references for specifying a model to estimate these transition rates, especially toward the observable terminal state, would be appreciated. In addition, if there is a totally different way to formulate the problem, that would be helpful, too.